# using django.views.generic.list.ListView in urlpatterns

Tags: django

I am new to Django and would greatly appreciate your help.

I have the below mentioned piece of code from an older book about Django. However, `django.views.generic.list_detail` has been deprecated. Can someone tell me how I could re-write this code with `django.views.generic.list.ListView`?

---

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from cmsproject.cms.models import Story

info_dict = {'queryset': Story.objects.all(), 'template_object_name': 'story'}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
     url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', info_dict, name="cms-story"),
     url(r'^$', 'object_list', info_dict, name="cms-home"),
)
```

Comment: What did you try? The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView) regarding this is quite good

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is fetch a list of Story model objects, this is one way to write your views.py and urls.py:

In views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView, DetailView

from cmsproject.cms.models import Story   

class StoryListView(ListView):
    model = Story
    template_name = "cms/story_list.html"

class StoryDetailView(DetailView): 
    model = Story
    template_name = "cms/story_detail.html"
```

`template_name` depends on where in the project you placed your html files. By setting `model = Story`, `ListView` will fetch `Story.objects.all()`. To customize, filter, add context etc., you can override any of the methods that your class based view inherits from its parent view (ex. in StoryListView you can override ListView methods).

In urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from cmsproject.cms.views import StoryDetailView, StoryListView 


    urlpatterns = patterns('',

         url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', StoryDetailView.as_view(), name="cms-story"),

         url(r'^$', StoryListView.as_view(), name="cms-home"),
    )
```

Think of urls.py as a mapping between the url and the View object. Defining `name` allows you to  refer/link to other views by including name as a parameter to url template tag in the templates.

Some Extremely Useful References:

- Effective Django - [Class Based Views](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/views.html#generic-class-based-views)
- CCBV [List View](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.list/ListView/)
- Django Project [Generic Display Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)
- [Built-in template Tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) -> look under **url**